# Program made to find the standard deviation of a set of inputted data not working correctly

Tags: python, function

I wrote this program so as to calculate the standard deviation of a given set of data but upon testing the program, I'm not getting correct answers, I've gone through the code and still can't find the problem.
The formula for calculating standard deviation if √Variance

This is the code I used

```
# THE AIM OF THIS CODE IS TO MAKE A PROGRAM THAT CALCULATES THE STANDARD DEVIATION OF A GIVEN SET OF INTEGERS

numbers = []

while True:

    value = (input("Enter Number: "))
    # Asks for input

    if value.lower() in ("", "q", "quit", "end", "stop", "s"):
        break
        # Instructs the program to break if the value of the input is any of these

    elif value.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(value))
        # appends the value of the input into the predefined list

    else:
        print("Invalid entry, enter only integers")
        # Tells the user to enter a correct value if he/she enters a non-integer

mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
#Calculates the mean of the given set data

for x in numbers:
    difference = []
    while len(difference) < len(numbers):
        x = x - mean
        #Calculates the difference between the input data and the mean and stores it to another list "difference"
        difference.append(x)

Variance = (sum(difference) ** 2) / len(numbers)
#Calculates the variance for the given set of data

import math

#Variances = 144 ignore this line

StandardDeviation = math.sqrt(Variance)
#Calculates the standard deviation of the input data

print("The Standard Deviation of the given set of data is " + str(StandardDeviation))
```

Comment: [PEP 450 – Adding A Statistics Module To The Standard Library](https://peps.python.org/pep-0450/)

Comment: Your variance is wrong, you are squaring the sum of differences, not summing the square differences.

Comment: Consider using functions. Had you started by solving the problem of calculating the variance instead of doing everything in one shot, you could have isolated the problem more easily. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = []

while True:

    value = (input("Enter Number: "))
    # Asks for input

    if value.lower() in ("", "q", "quit", "end", "stop", "s"):
        break
        # Instructs the program to break if the value of the input is any of these

    elif value.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(value))
        # appends the value of the input into the predefined list

    else:
        print("Invalid entry, enter only integers")
        # Tells the user to enter a correct value if he/she enters a non-integer

mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
#Calculates the mean of the given set data

n = 0
for x in numbers:
    n += (x - mean) ** 2



StandardDeviation = (n / (len(numbers) - 1)) ** 0.5

print(str(StandardDeviation))
```